# code for how to get phone no of a sms sender from received sms in android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, sms-gateway, phone-number

Please anyone give me downloaded code or any useful link for getting the phone number of a SMS sender while receiving a message.
I tried a lot.

Comment: Please share your code that you tried

Comment: Explain what you have tried so far. And have you looked for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html ?

Comment: Refer to this link http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this , here `messages[0].getOriginatingAddress()` will return the  phone number of a SMS sender

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

             if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                 if (bundle != null) {
                     Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                     final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                     for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                         messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                     }
                     if (messages.length > -1) {
                         Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                         Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getOriginatingAddress());
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
```

Hope it will work, or lead you to a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    //Log.d(Params.LOG_APP, "INCOMING SMS....");



    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras == null)
        return ;

    Object[] dataArr = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
    //Log.d(Params.LOG_APP, "dataArr ["+dataArr+"]");



    for (Object data: dataArr) {
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) data);
        //Log.d(Params.LOG_APP, "SMS ["+sms+"]");
        String body = sms.getMessageBody();
        String sender = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

        long time = sms.getTimestampMillis();

    }

}
```